# PDFBox - Invalid dictionary, found: '<' but expected: '/'

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I have to merge a set of PDF files using the `Apache PDFBox` library. Everything works fine except for some PDF problably not well-formed that make the `PDDocument.load()` to fail with the following error :

```
2016-01-20 14:59:59,069 WARN  [main] pdfparser.BaseParser (BaseParser.java:318) - Invalid dictionary, found: 'û' but expected: '/'
2016-01-20 14:59:59,070 WARN  [main] pdfparser.PDFParser (PDFParser.java:221) - Parsing Error, Skipping Object
java.io.IOException: Unknown dir object c=')' cInt=41 peek=')' peekInt=41 5840
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseDirObject(BaseParser.java:1364)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSDictionaryValue(BaseParser.java:251)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSDictionary(BaseParser.java:358)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseDirObject(BaseParser.java:1266)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseObject(PDFParser.java:641)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:203)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1249)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1214)
    ...
```

Here is my code :

```
PDDocument doc = null;

for (EscaleFile notice : noticeMetas.values()) {

    noticeFile = new File(noticesInputFilePath + notice.getPDFName());
    fis = new FileInputStream(noticeFile);

    try {

        doc = PDDocument.load(fis, true); // trigger here my error
        pdfMerger.appendDocument(finalPDF, doc);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (doc != null) {
            doc.close();
            fis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to use `PDDocument.loadNonSeq()` method instead, but same error...
The PDF that triggers the error is read by Adobe Reader without any error.
Another bad point is that I cannot share you the PDF as it contains confidential data...

I use `PDFBox 1.8.11` (and tried other versions) and `Java 1.6`.

Thanks for any help :)

**Edit :**

Here is where the problem seems to occur inside the file (character `û`, position `5840`) :
[image]

This is inside the `stream` part.

Comment: I don't know how to help you given that information. However you could identify the part of the file that causes the error by [checking the position in the input stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#getChannel%28%29). This may not be exact since a `BufferedReader` could be used, but at least it happens at some position before the current position... Maybe this is a part of the pdf that doesn't contain confidential information. In this case you could post that part (from PDF opened as text file).

Comment: Please try with the 2.0 version, open the file with the PDFReader tool of the command line app. Btw Adobe Reader often fails quietly, i.e. it will still open the file, but some parts may be blank.

Comment: The position is 5840. Open the file with NOTEPAD++, press CTRL-G and jump to that character (not line) position and make a screenshot.

Comment: @Truche *The PDF that triggers the error is read by Adobe Reader without any error.* - That hardly means anything. Adobe Reader has a long history of ignoring outright errors in PDF files. That may be ok for a PDF viewer. A PDF processor, on the other hand, which eventually is writing a resulting PDF itself, cannot so easily ignore errors.

Comment: Thanks. I added a screenshot from where the problem is. I hope it will help...
@TilmanHausherr I also tried API with version 2.0 and I didn't get more information, but I'll try with the command line app.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't help, sorry. (Sometimes I can solve problems with a screenshot, but not this time)

Comment: I tried PDFBox command line app (v 2.0.0), same error...
Other ideas ?